# How and why strtok remembers string?

Tags: c, string, split, strtok, libc

In following C program, `strtok` is used to split the string. Program is giving excepted output, but I am not able to understand how it works.

First, we have passed *string to tokenize* and *delimiter*. But in later iterations, we are just passing `NULL`. **How** and **why** function remembers string?

What if I want to use tokenize to different string simultaneously?

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <cstdio>
#include <cstring>

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    char arr[] = "This is string to split";

    char * subStr = new char[10];
    subStr = strtok(arr, " ");

    while (subStr)
    {
        printf("%s\n", subStr);
        subStr = strtok(NULL, " ");
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Output:

```
This
is
string
to
split
```

Comment: If it will not remember how will it know which token to return, the first one or the second one or the last one.

Comment: @MadHatter, There can be ways, we can pass new string again and again. Question is, current approach doesn't make it to work for only one string at time.

Comment: For "how it remembers" may be `static pointer`. I don't think Dynamic allocation can be used, since when will it know to `free` the memory.

Comment: And the ways are... (without remembering something)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The `strtok` function has an internal state that remembers the last position which it has reached. Since it overwrites the original string by replacing the token with zero, all it needs to remember is the next position in the string. If you call `strtok` with a non-null string argument, the internal state is reset to the new string. So indeed, you cannot use it on multiple strings at once, only one after the other. (Some platforms provide the reentrant variant `strtok_r` which allows you to pass your own state variable.)

Here's a sample implementation:

```
char * my_strtok(char * in, char delim)   // not quite the same signature
{
    _Thread_local static char * pos = NULL;

    if (in) { pos = in; }

    char * p = find_next_delimiter(pos, delim);    // NULL if not found
    if (p) { *p = '\0'; ++p; pos = p; }

    return p;
}
```

(The real `strtok` searches for any delimiter of a given list, and also skips over empty fields.) The reentrant variant of this would replace the static variable `pos` with a function parameter.

Answer (score 0):

The `strtok` function uses a static variable to keep track of state from previous calls.  For this reason, it's not thread safe (check out `strtok_r` instead) and you should not use it to simultaneously tokenize different strings on different threads.

[Here](http://www.opensource.apple.com/source/Libc/Libc-167/string.subproj/strtok.c) is one way it might be implemented.

Comment: Note: `strtok_r` is non-standard and not available on every platform.

Comment: Why would it not be thread-safe? It's entirely plausible that the internal state is thread-local, much like `errno`.

Comment: @KerrekSB  Good point.  It *could*.  But is it guaranteed somewhere to be so? (I don't know -- I'm honestly asking.)  If not, I would want to know the specifics about the version I'm using.  (And, for example, that link I included leads me to believe that care should be taken...)  In such circumstances where an assumption must be made, I choose to assume it's not rather than it is.

Comment: @Turix: You're right, the C11 standard even says explicitly that there is no requirement to avoid data races. (By contrast, `errno` is required to be thread-local.) There's an optionally standardized `strtok_s` that has a state parameter.

Answer (score 0):

"How" = using static variable.

"Why" = for continue require next behind zero, if you pass original string again -- you will need again skip first tokens, that loose of CPU cycles

Answer (score 0):

> How and why strtok remembers string?

The `strtok()` function uses a static buffer while parsing.

> What if I want to use tokenize to different string simultaneously?

You can build your own:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

char *scan(char **pp, char c)
{
    char *s = *pp, *p;

    p = strchr(*pp, c);
    if (p) *p++ = '\0';
    *pp = p;
    return s;
}

int main(void)
{
    char s[] = "This is string to split";
    char *p = s;

    while (p) {
        printf("%s\n", scan(&p, ' '));
    }
    return 0;
}
```

- Note that `scan()` replaces all ocurrences of delimiter with `\0` in the original string